# alias value in where clause for the same query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to get result where distance >=distance_filter which we are fetching in same query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as row, distance_filter, j.lat, j.long, ROUND((((acos(sin((28.53551600*pi()/180)) * sin((j.lat*pi()/180)) + cos((28.53551600*pi()/180)) * cos((j.lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((77.39102600 - j.long) * pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344 )) as distance, j.job_id, j.brand, j.location, j.model, j.creation_time
FROM `mb_job` as `j`
JOIN `mb_job_issue` as `ji` ON `j`.`job_id`=`ji`.`job_id`
WHERE `j`.`creation_time` >= '2017-05-18 09:39:43'
AND `j`.`status` = '1'
AND `j`.`job_id` NOT IN('')
GROUP BY `j`.`job_id`
HAVING `distance` <= 'DISTANCE_FILTER'
ORDER BY `j`.`job_id` DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: Remove the quotes from 'DISTANCE_FILTER' in your HAVING and it should work (although the case differs from your select: distance_filter versus DISTANCE_FILTER)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put  having clause inside a single quote. This query is working fine at my end

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as row, distance_filter, j.lat, j.long, ROUND((((acos(sin((28.53551600*pi()/180)) * sin((j.lat*pi()/180)) + cos((28.53551600*pi()/180)) * cos((j.lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((77.39102600 - j.long) * pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344 )) as distance, j.job_id, j.brand, j.location, j.model, j.creation_time
FROM `mb_job` as `j`
JOIN `mb_job_issue` as `ji` ON `j`.`job_id`=`ji`.`job_id`
WHERE `j`.`creation_time` >= '2017-05-18 09:39:43'
AND `j`.`status` = '1'
AND `j`.`job_id` NOT IN('')
GROUP BY `j`.`job_id`
HAVING 'distance <= distance_filter'
ORDER BY `j`.`job_id` DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use whole calculation like

`WHERE ROUND((((acos(sin((28.53551600*pi()/180)) * sin((j.lat*pi()/180)) + cos((28.53551600*pi()/180)) * cos((j.lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((77.39102600 - j.long) * pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344 )) >= distance filter`

Or you could transfer that to the HAVING clause:
`HAVING distance >= distance_filter`